# d3 rectangles not appending

Tags: javascript, d3.js, append, nested

I'm new to d3 and am attempting to plot rectangles from data I had stored in a MySQL db.  Here's the script:

```
function populate_isoforms(data){

var min_locus = parseInt(data[0].protein_dat.min_locus);
var max_locus = parseInt(data[0].protein_dat.max_locus);
var num_isoforms = parseInt(data[0].protein_dat.num_isoforms);

data = data[0].isoforms;

for (var key in data) {
if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
var val = data[key];
var loci = val.loci;
console.log(val.loci[0].s)

var width = $(window).width()-50;
var height = 100;

var widthScale = d3.scale.linear()
.domain([min_locus,max_locus])
.range([0,width]);
var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", 20);
var boxes = svgContainer.selectAll("g")
.data(loci)
.enter()
.append("g");
var box_attrs = boxes.selectAll("g")
.data(function(d){return d;})
.enter().append("rect")
.attr("x",function(d){return widthScale(d.s);})
.attr("y",10)
.attr("stroke","red")
.attr("width", function(d){return widthScale(d.e);})
.attr("fill","grey")
.attr("height", 15);
}
}

}
```

The data format is like so:

['{"protein_dat": {"max_locus": "43535079", "min_locus": "43530174", "num_isoforms": 2}, "isoforms": [{"loci": [{"s": "43530174", "e": "43530474"}, {"s": "43532633", "e": "43532757"}, {"s": "43533608", "e": "43533772"}, {"s": "43534641", "e": "43534737"}, {"s": "43535022", "e": "43535079"}], "name": "uc002xmt.3"}, {"loci": [{"s": "43530174", "e": "43530474"}, {"s": "43532633", "e": "43532757"}, {"s": "43533608", "e": "43533772"}, {"s": "43534641", "e": "43534737"}, {"s": "43535022", "e": "43535079"}], "name": "uc002xmu.3"}]}']

The problem I'm having is that nothing displays because no rect elements are appending to the g elements.  I'm sure it's simple, but I cannot make it work.  Any help would be excellent.  Thanks.

Comment: It looks like the nested call to `.data()` should be `.data(function(d) { return d.isoforms; })` and then another nested call? What exactly are you trying to plot?

Comment: Thanks Lars.  I've printed d inside the nested .data() with console.log and it gives me:  Object {s: "43530174", e: "43530474"}
test2.html:107 Object {s: "43532633", e: "43532757"}
test2.html:107 Object {s: "43533608", e: "43533772"}
test2.html:107 Object {s: "43534641", e: "43534737"}
test2.html:107 Object {s: "43535022", e: "43535079"} which is what I want.  The issue is that the rectangles are not being appended.  This is bio data that contains the start and end locations of dna sequences responsible for transcripts that code for proteins.  I just want a rectangle to plot for each range.

Comment: The DOM just looks like: <svg><g></g>...</svg> but it should look like: <svg><g><rect>.....</g></rect></svg>

Comment: Have you tried `boxes.selectAll("rect")`?

Comment: I have tried that without success.  The DOM looks the same.

Comment: The problem is that you need to return an array from the data function for the matching to work: http://jsfiddle.net/nw9gwuu5/ If you *know* that there's only ever going to be a single element, you don't need the nested selection and can append directly: http://jsfiddle.net/nw9gwuu5/1/

Comment: So which of the two did you intend to do?